# Are all JavaScript features available in Windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, microsoft-metro

When designing Metro apps for Windows 8 with JavaScript, are all features available such as full AJAX support? And what about CSS?

What is supported, and what is not? I haven't been able to find a comprehensive command-reference list yet.

Comment: I cant imagine why something as standard as CSS and js not being supported.

Comment: So if I make an AJAX request to download a page, will that work? I doubt that.

Comment: JavaScript and AJAX are as different as C# is from .Net Framework. You get all the language features of JavaScript, but you will need to use WinRT API to download data from a url asynchronously!

Comment: Not exactly, @decyclone. You don't use the WinRT API to fetch data asynchronously. You use WinJS. And it's certainly not the only way to do it. You can include jQuery and use $.getJSON or any other library that's based on the standard XmlHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JavaScript [Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx) page, you can create apps with HTML (so I assume full DOM access), as well as network requests using XMLHttpRequest.

Check out the blog reader demo app.

Comment: Righto. The only things that don't work the exact same as IE10 are where a) it's not relevant on a native platform (i.e. window.open) or b) it's not safe by default. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx for more than you ever needed to know :)

Answer (score 3):

You are asking it wrong ;) Windows 8 [WinJS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) has **much more** features than in-browser JavaScript in Windows 8 / IE10.

Update: thanx to Jeremy Poster, for pointing out, there are some security limitation in Windows Store Apps (because it has more privileges, compared to browser). Most visible are:  mandatory utf8, absence of `window.alert` and its friends, url links open in browser by default, .js file caching, and filtration for `.innerHTML` and company. See all [differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx#differences).

Comment: JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS in A Windows 8 Store application is exactly the same as IE10 -- which is as good as, and many ways better than WebKit.

Additionally, you get a boat load of extra support through the WinJS library, and WinRT

Comment: Not exactly the same. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx for the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript in Metro runs on IE10 browser, you can check http://caniuse.com/ for information about which browser supports what. In addition, there are additional APIS you can use from "WinRT".